# Using FindRoot in a function definition

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I want to define a function as the result of FindRoot. This function will be used in other functions. For example:

```
f[a_] := FindRoot[2*x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]];
g[a_] := 1 - f[a];
```

When I plug in numbers for a, there everything works perfectly:

```
f[1]
g[1]
0.787179
0.212821
```

The problem happens when I am defining other functions that will use f[a] and g[a] in symbolic terms:

```
h[a_]:=5*f[a];
h[a]
5 Log[x]
```

This happens because when I call f[a] in a symbolic way the result is the following, which is wrong:

```
f[a]
Log[x]
```

I am clearly not defining f[a] properly or calling it properly in symbolic terms. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you run `FindRoot[2*x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]]` without a numeric value of `a`, then you get an error.

Comment: Yes, of course. Maybe I was not very clear. I want to put a "hold" on the FindRoot so I can use f[a] and g[a] symbolically until they are finally evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Clear[f]
f[a_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[2 x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]]
f[a_] := 
  Inactivate[FindRoot[2*x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]], FindRoot | Part]

f[1]
```

> `0.787179`

```
f[a]
```

> ```
> Inactive[Part][Inactive[FindRoot][-a + 2*x^2 + Log[x], {x, 0.01}], 1, 2]
> ```

```
h[a_] := 5 f[a]
ih = h[a]
```

> ```
> 5 Inactive[Part][Inactive[FindRoot][-a + 2 x^2 + Log[x], {x, 0.01}], 1, 2]
> ```

```
hv = ih /. a -> 1 // Activate
```

> `3.93589`

```
hv/f[1]
```

> `5.`

Comment: That is absolutely great. Thank you very much, @m_goldberg!