# FindRoot when variable is inside a piecewise function

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise

I want to find the root of a function that has a piecewise part. This means that the value Mathematica will search will determine in which piece of the function we will be. I don't my example is the best, but this is the best example I could think of (and thank you [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) for helping be to [Inactivate the function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158819/using-findroot-in-a-function-definition)):

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[2 x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]]
f[a_] := Inactivate[FindRoot[2*x^2 + Log[x] - a, {x, 0.01}][[1, 2]], 
  FindRoot | Part]
g[a_] := Piecewise[{{1 - f[a] + Log[f[a]], 
    a <= 1}, {Log[2*f[a]] + f[a], a > 1}}]
Findroot[g[a] + Log[a], {a, 0.1, 0.01, 10}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define `g` using [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ) just as you did for `f` instead of using [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate):

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[2 x^2+Log[x]-a, {x,0.01}][[1,2]]
g[a_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{
    {1-f[a]+Log[f[a]],a<=1},
    {Log[2*f[a]]+f[a],a>1}
}]
```

Then try using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
FindRoot[g[a] + Log[a], {a,0.1,0.01,10}]
```

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
>
> {a -> 1.}

Let's plot your expression over the region of interest:

```
Plot[g[a] + Log[a], {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) message occurs because the root occurs at the piecewise boundary.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Carl Woll. Indeed my example was not the best because of this boundary issue, but on my problem this is not the case. Thank you again!